# send() got an unexpected keyword argument 'view'

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am unfamiliar with the new `discord.View` class and I don't know how to use it. I have searched in Google and didn't found any result. (They're all off-topic)

An example of using `discord.View` can be found from an extension called Jishaku. When you run the command `jishaku cat <filename>`, it will return the `<filename>`'s source, in a paginator, with some buttons.

```yaml
Usage: jsk cat main.py
```

How do I use views in my own code?

[image]

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: @ChaoticNebula sure. One moment.

Comment: Ok, the code is in [here](https://pastebin.com/8hFFsLZv). The password to unlock the paste is `KjxUCCP9XS`. @ChaoticNebula

Comment: You can just paste the code here, using three back-ticks '`'.

Comment: @ChaoticNebula the code is too big, so I couldn't send it.